# iOS XMLParser and UITabeView

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Добрый день iГуру мне нужна ваша помошь. Есть код XML, я его паршу. В нем есть Авторы, в каждом Авторе куча цытат (реализованно UITabeView). Мне нужно было определить есть ли под  Автором цытаты. Я сделал цыкл (как смог) что б в таблице где авторы, парсинг заохдил на уровень ниже и смотрет наличии цытат. Все получилось, лишнии название исчезли, но вот теперь у меня по 4-5 авторов оденаковых. И вот тут я зашел в тупик.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil array:(NSArray*)test
{
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

     self.package = [NSMutableArray array];

    if (self) {

            for (int i = 0; i < [test count]; i++)  {

            SMXMLElement *elem = [test objectAtIndex:i];

                NSArray* packageArray = [elem childrenNamed:@"citation"];

                for (int y = 0; y < [packageArray count]; y++)  {
                SMXMLElement  *elemT = [packageArray objectAtIndex:y];
                NSString *str = [elemT attributeNamed:@"text"];

                    if (str.length > 0)
                    {
                        [self.package addObject:elem];
                    }

                }

            }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Я думаю что где-то запутался в цыкле. Но просмотрев все так и не нашел ошибки =( Буду очень благодарен любой помоши!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цикл не причем, вы сначала пытаетесь проинициировать свойство package у self и только потом создаете сам self, который в таком случае не содержит ссылки на созданный package. Поменяйте местами строки 1 и 2 (не считая пустых)

А вообще более правильным будет перенести self.package = [NSMutableArray array]; внутрь if (self) {

Comment: Безусловно это ошибка, спасибо, но чуда с основной проблемой не произошло =((

Comment: А вот вам еще ошибка, проверяем одно, а добавляем другое:

                NSString *str = [___elemT___ attributeNamed:@"text"];

                    if (str.length > 0)
                    {
                        [self.package addObject:___elem____];
                    }

Ну или, если я неверно понял смысл действия, пропущен break для вложенного for. Вообще вы бы подебажили прежде чем спрашивать, посмотреди бы чему тот или иной элемент соответствует в рантайме

Comment: Этот елемент стоит правильно. elemT это проверка цытат, е elem авторы xD знаю так писать не коректно. Я дебажил. Всячески и проверял это... Не думайте, я не от лени спрашиваю.

Comment: а, понял, вы проверяете что у автора есть хотя бы один элемент с не пустой цитатой, так? Тогда зачем вам пробегать по всем элементам? Вам достаточно найти первый такой элемент для автора, если он найден - добавить автора в массив package  и прервать цикл пробежки по цитатам (break после [self.package addObject:elem];
), сейчас же у вас автор добавляется столько раз, сколько у него цитат  - элементы массива не обязаны быть уникальными, один и тот же объект может входить в массив сколь угодно много раз. Собственно об этом я и писал в конце предыдущего коммента